# After migration in to localhost, my magento have a little error in link n images display

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

I have a problem with my new magento after migration in localhost, my image n several link in my frontend is not displayed, when i trying to copy the link location from both old n new magento to, n the result is different. 
My old different copied link is :

```
http://www.test.com/customer/account/login/
```

n my new copied link is :

```
http://www.test2.com/%3C?=$this-%3EgetUrl(
```

but when i tried to see the script in `header.phtml`, the scripts are the same. here the script..

...`$this->getUrl('customer/account/login')?>' title='Login'>Login<`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old link server supports php short tag, while your new one doesn't. Check your php.ini file in your new server and make sure this is there: `short_open_tag=On`

Another solution would be, replace all `<?=` to `<?php echo` and you should be good to go.

Comment: my new image url in my new magento is :
http://localhost/magento_141/%3C?=$this-%3EgetSkinUrl()?%3Eimages/banner/1.jpg

my new image url in my new magento is :
http://www.test.com/skin/frontend/angzcommerz/default/images/banner/1.jpg

Comment: @user1477136 open your php.ini in your new server. search for `short_open_tag`. I guess it will be Off, you should turn it on and restart the server.

Comment: thank's mr., it's worked, i forget to restart my apache. Thanks again.